# What is the difference between "talk over" and "talk about"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between *talk over*, and *talk about*? For example:

> I came up with the idea of how to boost sales and I would like to **talk about** it with the boss.
>
> I came up with the idea of how to boost sales and I would like to **talk it over** with the boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Talk it over" idiomatically means to *discuss thoroughly*. Talking "about" something can mean this, but not so specifically. "Talk over" also suggests that you talked with a view to achieving an outcome, or a decision. "Talk about" covers more general, casual conversation.

In your example, either work fine - because you have stated a topic for discussion (your sales idea) and who you are discussing it with (your boss) it is pretty clear that you intend to achieve something as it is a work-related discussion. Still, "talk over" does sound like you were more thorough and achieved something at the end of it rather than just a preliminary discussion.

Answer (score 0):

"Talk about it" could mean anything from just mentioning it to discussing it at length. "Talk it over" suggests a more extensive discussion.